# For orthogonal matrices $A$ and $B$, does $ABAB=BABA$ imply $A$ and $B$ commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Given two distinct orthogonal matrices $A$ and $B$, given some individual sequence of applications of these matrices such that each matrix appears an equal number of times (e.g. $AABBAB$, with $3$ occurrences of each matrix), if the application of this sequence is equal to the application of the sequences dual, where each of our matrices is replaced by the other (e.g. $AABBAB=BBAABA$), do $A$ and $B$ necessarily commute ($AB=BA$)?

This is clearly a sufficient condition, but is it a necessary one?

I am trying to show $A$ and $B$ must belong to a subgroup of $O(n)$ isomorphic to $O(2)$.

It also bears note that both $A$ and $B$ must vary continuously according to some parameter $t\in (0,1)$ while retaining this property.

Edit: it seems that should $A$ and $B$ satisfy this condition, then $A$ may be replaced by any element $B^ZAB^{-Z}$.

To clarify my question: if one sequence of applications of the two matrices $A$ and $B$ in equal number is equal to the dual of that sequence made by swapping the matrices, are the matrices $A$ and $B$ necessarily commutative?

Comment: Your title poses a very clear question, but the body of your post confuses things. Can you please specify very precisely what your question is?

Comment: My title poses a simpler form of the question. I am interested in answers to both.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez What I meant to convey was that the solutions that interest me are those such that for all solutions, there is another solution arbitrarily close to the original.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Why must $C_0=I$? Sorry, it doesn't seem apparent to me.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right), 
\quad B = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
Then $$BA = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right) \ne 
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right) = AB.$$
But $(AB)^2=(BA)^2=-I_2$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to construct two matrices $A$ and $A$ such that $(AB)^n=(BA)^n$ for some $n$. Take two reflections with respect to lines that form an angle of $2\pi/n$. They don't commute.

On a different line, take two matrices $A$ and $B$ of order $3$ that do not commute and notice that $AAABBB=BBBAAA$.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title: no.

The condition $ABAB = BABA$ can be equivalently written as $(AB)^2 = (BA)^2$. Can we have orthogonal  matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $(AB)^2 = (BA)^2$ without having $AB = BA$?

The answer is yes, because this can happen in finite groups! For example, in the quaternion group $Q_8$, we have $(ij)^2 = k^2 = -1 = (-k)^2 = (ji)^2$, but $ij = k \neq -k = ji$.

Every finite group admits a faithful orthogonal action, so this answers the question in the negative. This example in $Q_8$ yields the matrices

$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right), \quad B = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which are indeed orthogonal and satify $ABAB=BABA$, but do not commute.